# Linux recovery mode graphics state Versus the normal graphics state

Tags: ubuntu, boot, nvidia-graphics-card, linux-kernel

What does  booting to [`recovery mode`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) then selecting  `resume normal boot`  do to the systems graphics? 
(on linux  distributions like Debian)

I'd like to know things like:

What makes this state "safe". : ( because it uses open source  drivers?)  

Why do I have to reboot to get proprietary drivers to work?

Does it compare with the kernel parameters: [nomodeset, quiet, splash,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-)

There is a lot of information on how to enter & do things in`recovery mode`, but what about `recovery mode` itself?

I'm hoping for a technical answer about the graphic side of things (for future reference).

Comment: There’s no standard there. The Ubuntu wiki mentions options coming up, but it could also just start a root shell or even start a graphics environment using VESA drivers (essentially what Windows does).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with [run levels](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel), which selects a set of auto-started services.

Recovery mode (which usually selects either run level `S` or `1`) starts a very minimal set of services. It does not start graphical, network or antivirus ones to cite a few.

You can see a list of services installed on your system this way:

```
ls /etc/init.d/
```

You will see there is a bunch of services. Only a very few of them is started in recovery mode which lower the risk of issue. You can then start some more services manually if you want, backup your files and try to fix any boot issue before rebooting in standard run level (usually `2` or `5`).

---

From the graphical point of view, the recovery mode does not start graphical driver (named *modules* in Linux) which is often loaded by the non-started graphical service. Instead, it uses limited generic graphic console features which requires no specific module.

Graphical modules are big and complex, and can crash your computer when they misbehave. If you experience issue with them, then you will love recovery mode which will let you fix it using a reliable environment.

Recovery mode compares with optional kernel parameter `1`, or whichever is the specific run level you want to join instead of the default one.